# How to create Factory for Generic Class

Tags: c#

I have next interface

```
public interface IProperty<T>
{       
    T Data { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SomeAbsProperty<T> : IProperty<T> where T : class
{
    protected SomeAbsProperty(int param1) {}
    public abstract T GetData();
    public I Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I have list of  childres classes that based on SomeAbsProperty class
they looks like (simple example)

```
public sealed class ChildrenProperties : SomeAbsProperty<SomeClasss>
{
    public ChildrenProperties(int param1):base(param1) {}
    public override object GetData()
    {
        return new SomeClasss()
    }
}
```

I would like to have some factory that would build specific class based on some type

```
public static class MyFactory
{
    public static SomeAbsProperty<T> CreateObject<T>(PropertyName property) where T : class
    {
        switch (property)
        {
            case PropertyName.p1:
                return new ChildrenProperties1(siteSettings, packageDateContext);
            case PropertyName.p2:
                return new ChildrenProperties(siteSettings, packageDateContext);
            case PropertyName.p3:
                return new ChildrenProperties2(siteSettings, packageDateContext);
            case PropertyName.p4:
                return new ChildrenProperties3(siteSettings, packageDateContext);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

but compelator can't convert my clases to SomeAbsProperty 
what would be correct behavior here ?

Comment: Only one code should decide what a concrete class we need. It is either CreateObject<SomeClass> or "return new SomeClass()".
What code would do if we call CreateObject<SomeClass2> and pass a property that corresponding to ChildrenProperties3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as` casting to `SomeAbsProperty<T>` generic class, something like

```
return new ChildrenProperties(10) as SomeAbsProperty<T>;
```

Of-course you must be sure that ChildrenProperties is indeed SomeAbsProperty (which you know it is if you wrote base classes and factory class). You can not use explicit compile time casting.

Edit:
Maybe its better if factory which creates instances only depends on generic parameter (this will work only if all specializations have different parameter T; I'm not sure if that is your situation). Something like:

```
        public static SomeAbsProperty<T> CreateObject<T>() where T : class
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            if (type == typeof(object))
            {
                return new ChildrenProperties() as SomeAbsProperty<T>;
            }
            else if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                return new ChildrenPropertiesString() as SomeAbsProperty<T>;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

... then you can call factory with something like:

```
SomeAbsProperty<object> h = MyFactory.CreateObject<object>();
Console.WriteLine(h.GetType().ToString());
SomeAbsProperty<string> h2 = MyFactory.CreateObject<string>();
Console.WriteLine(h2.GetType().ToString());
```

Comment: That will compile, but the risk is that if `ChildrenProperties(10)` is not a `SomeAbsProperty<T>` (which you can't know at compile-time) then you'll get `null` back.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but he created ChildrenProperties class which he knows is SomeAbsProperty<T>, so I think this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: But you don't know what `T` was used to call the method so there's no guarantee that they match.

Comment: You made a good point. I have updated my answer which proposes only generic parameter for resolving which class should be instantiated. If author has all different generic class specializations this may work for him better